# Rename folder using script, variables from excel doc

Tags: microsoft-excel, script, rename, mv

Linux File System

I have a directory with 1500 folders.  I am looking to use an excel document that has the 1500 folder names in one column and a unique id in the next.  I am looking to script it so the script reanames the folders to the new unique id.  Can anyone help me seems very easy although I do not know how to write scripts.  Can anyone provide a link to a script online ( I have not been able to find one).

```
Look at volume A for folder Var#1 (from excel)

if present on Volume A then mv Var#1 to Var#2 (from excel)

loop and grab next line of excel doc
```

Comment: If this isn't answered when I get home I will be back, but until then - start with exporting the excel to a CSV.  Then from there you could use a combination of *rename* and *awk*.

Comment: ?: Are all the folders in the same directory, or do you need it to scan cross-system for folder A?

Comment: I agree that exporting to a CSV and working from there is a good approach — except that gets tricky if any of the old names have commas in them.  An alternative is to export to a Tab delimited text file.  Of course, if the old names contain tabs, we have the same problem.  And as @Richard pointed out, spaces and tabs in the old names cause issues with most solutions.

Answer (score 2):

Ok, here it is:

> for i in $(cat test.csv)
>
> do
>
> dir1=$(echo $i|sed 's/,.*//')
>
> dir2=$(echo $i|sed 's/.*,//')
>
> if [ -d $dir1]
>
> then
>
> if [ -d $dir2 ]
>
> then
>
> echo $dir2 present, skipping move from $dir1 to $dir2
>
> else
>
> mv $dir1 $dir2
>
> fi
>
> fi
>
> done

Comment: Not sure if you tested that or not, but that does not work.  It prints "cat\ntest.csv" as ${i}  You need to wrap "cat test.csv" in $(cat test.csv)

Comment: Then it should work.

Comment: @nerdwaller: Give the guy a break!  He typed `for i in \`cat test.csv\`` without realizing how Super User would interpret the back-ticks as formatting controls.

Comment: I attempted to edit  my comment but it was too late per SU's policy.  So I do owe an apology for that coming across negatively (unintentional).

Comment: Thanks Scott, after reading the comments I tried to get the back ticks to show up with no luck.  I should have used $(cat test.csv), reads more clearly anyway. Do you know how to put back ticks in?

Comment: @Richard, you probably tried this - but I am not sure if escape character's work?  \'cat test.csv\' (I assume in comments and answers format that differently)?  Again, I apologize my comment came across as crass.

Comment: @nerdwaller: I was able to find three ways to get back ticks to show up: (1) Use backslashes.  (2) Type four spaces before each line of code.  (3) Type <pre> at the beginning of your code block and </pre> at the end.  See the [Super User Markdown Editing Help](http://superuser.com/editing-help), particularly the [Preformatted Text](http://superuser.com/editing-help#code) and [Inline HTML](http://superuser.com/editing-help#html) sections.

Answer (score 0):

So, I'm a linux, unix, and mac user and write perl and bash scripts.  If you have a power shell or cygwin you can do the follow, Windows might have this too but don't hold your breath:

Without doing the whole thing, I think you should be able to take this and mod the way you want...

- Save your data to a csv file (somefile.csv)
- In a bash shell

> bash> for temp_line in `cat somefile.csv`
>
> > do
> >
> > echo mv $temp_line |sed 's/,/ /'
>
> done >somefile.sh

Don't run the following line until you are sure it's going to do what you want it to do!

> bash>. ./somefile.sh

That should be it... Note, this is a quick hack, this can be written with more error checking and what nots, and this was off the top of my head:)  Another issue you might run into is spaces in the file/dir names, just add quotes.  If you need to check if the directory is present you can add an if statement like the following:

> bash>if [ -d 'dir_name' ]; then ... ;fi

That should be enough nuggets without writing it.  I might get inspired later and write this in a follow up post.

Answer (score 0):

This is **not an answer**, but I’m entering it as one because comments don’t allow decent formatting, or this much text.

Obviously, the names of the existing folders are unique (assuming they are either all in the same super-folder, or they are presented as full pathnames — as pointed out by @nerdwaller).  And the unique IDs in the second column are, by definition, unique. 
Are the two columns unique (non-overlapping)?  Consider the following data:

```
          Old name            New unique ID
To_be,_or_not_to_be,                1
that_is_the_question.               2
The_quick_brown_fox                 3
jumps_over_the_lazy_dog.            4
             ⋮                     ⋮
Once_upon_a_midnight_dreary,       40
while_I_pondered,                  41
weak_and_weary,                    42
             ⋮                     ⋮
The_answer_to_the                  56
ultimate_question_of_life,         57
the_universe,_and_everything_is    58
42                                 59
And_so_on...                       60
```

If/when you try to rename `weak_and_weary,` to `42`, you will collide with the existing `42` folder.  Probably the best way to address this is to check the old folder names for names that match the pattern of the unique IDs, and handle them manually.

Comment: Thanks to all that have responded with solutions for my issue. I will be working on this over the next week or so.  I will let you all know how it goes or if I run into any issues that are show stoppers.

Comment: @Mike: Glad to help, and welcome to Super User.  By the way, when you write a comment that’s targeted at specific people, it’s conventional to mention their names, preceded by “@” symbols, as in “@Richard, @nerdwaller”.  That way we get notified.  See the **Replying in comments** paragraphs of [the **Comment formatting** section](http://superuser.com/editing-help#comment-formatting) of the Markdown Editing Help page.